# What is this word? 丒

Tags: simplified-characters

stumbled across this word

```
丒
```

and have no clue what it is. Context is 辛丒

Can anyone tell me how to spell it, and most importantly what does it mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The character you posted is [丒](https://www.zdic.net/hant/%E4%B8%92) /chǒu/

> “醜”的俗字。

丒 is a variant of 醜 (Traditional ) / 丑 (simplified)

[辛丑](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BE%9B%E4%B8%91)

2021 is a 辛丑年, the last 辛丑年 was 1961, the next one will 2081

Comment: I don't know why all Chinese dictionaries indicate 丒 is the simplified 醜, as each has very different meanings and uses except the overlapping in ugly. https://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/meancompare/4E11/919C

Comment: That's why I use 辛丑 instead of 辛丒. 辛醜/丒 is wrong. 丑 is used as a traditional character when it means the second Earthly Branch (we write 丑時 not 醜時)

Comment: Now you know my concerns. The original Chinese word (繁體字) usually has the same meanings and uses as its simplified version (簡字). This is not the case though,

Comment: The problem seems to be 丑 is now used as standard simplified 醜 and 丑 (繁體字), while 丒 was a simplified version of  醜 in the old days. And the dictionary is wrong to state 醜/ 丒 has the same meaning of the 繁體字  '丑'

Comment: Seems logically correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

丑 has these meanings:

- ugly - 他長的好丑(醜).
- disgraceful - 丑(醜)化, 丑(醜)事, 丑(醜)聞.

**In the above usages, 丑 and 醜 are interchangeable.**

- clown - 小丑
- 2nd Earthly Branch - 丑时1～3点. (see note)

**Note:** Earthly Branch (地支) is an old Chinese ordering system. There are twelve Earthly Branches used to count time of years, months, and hours - 十二时辰：子时23～1点，丑时1～3点，寅时3～5点，卯时5～7点，辰时7～9点，巳时9～11点，午时11～13点，未时13～15点，申时15～17点，酉时17～19点，戌时19～21点，亥时21～23点。

**ADD:** In addition to time, the combination of Earthly Branches was used to indicate the numerical order of a year in the old Chinese calendar system (干支), which considered 60 years as a complete cycle. The last famously known Chinese year of 辛丑 is 1901 (Western Calendar). Then, by addition of 60, the following years of 辛丑 are 1961, 2021, 2081...